.cf: operation not permitted
I am running a MacBookPro with an M3 and tried to install the cf-cli.
First I tried:
brew install cloudfoundry/tap/cf-cli@8

This failed with an error related tot the XCode Command Line Tools, so I tried to install it via the binary.
Just noticed now, that there isnt mentioned that the binary already supports M3 ..
Nevertheless, it runs through.
When I executed:
cf --version

It failed with:
mkdir /Users/XYZ/.cf: operation not permitted
FAILED

After updating my XCode Command Line Tools I could install cf-cli via brew.
But still I get the operation not permitted error.
If I run brew list cf-cli@8
It seems to find the installed files:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cf-cli@8/8.8.3/bin/cf
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cf-cli@8/8.8.3/bin/cf8
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cf-cli@8/8.8.3/etc/bash_completion.d/cf8-cli
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cf-cli@8/8.8.3/sbom.spdx.json
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cf-cli@8/8.8.3/share/doc/ (2 files)


Check whether the /Users/XYZ/.cf node already exists (and maybe is not a directory), and whether the /Users/XYZ/ folder exists and is writeable by the user cf runs as. If necessary and if you are the XYZ user, try creating the directory yourself with wide permissions: mkdir /Users/XYZ/.cf ; chmod 0777 /Users/XYZ/.cf.

Thank you! I can't create a folder in /Users/XYZ Seems like it is related to this problem https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos
There have to be an other solution without changing System Integrity Protection

@Dawienchi SIP shouldn't be restricting access to your home directory (I assume that's what /Users/XYZ is); it's more likely to be the privacy protection system TCC ("Transparency, Consent, and Control", see this question). I'm not sure why it'd consider ~/.cf private, but if that's it you probably need to grant the Terminal app access in the Security & Privacy preferences.
